# Adding font awesome spinning cog to jquery click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I need to add the font awesome spinning cog while the data is being retrieved and remove it when it's done.

This is the html to be added:

```
<i class="fa fa-spin fa-cog"></i>
```

And this is the script:

```
(function($) {
  $('.acf-get-content-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $contentWrapper = $( '#acf-content-wrapper' );
    var postId = $contentWrapper.data( 'id' );

    $.ajax({
      url: "/field-ajax.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        'post_id': postId
      },
    })
      .done(function( data ) {
        $contentWrapper.append( data );
        $('.acf-get-content-button').removeClass().addClass('.acf-get-content-button')
      });
  });
  $('.acf-get-content-button').mouseup(function(){
      if (event.which == 1) {
        $(".acf-get-content-button").hide();
      }
        });
})(jQuery);
```

I have been searching for a while but none of the examples i've found look enough like my script to implement it (i'm not a programmer).

Comment: Using jQuery [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) you can add the classes you need as you execute ajax and your code already used remove class so use that again in the `done` to remove it.

Comment: Correct see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the icon in a 'off' and 'gone' status by removing `fa-cog` and `fa-spin` like so:

> ```
> <i class="fa"></i>
> ```

Add the following:

> ```
> $('.fa').addClass('fa-cog fa-spin')
> ```

and

> ```
> $('.fa').removeClass('fa-cog fa-spin')
> ```

See Snippet as to where they should be.

**REFERENCE:** https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

**SNIPPET**

```js
(function($) {
  $('.acf-get-content-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.fa').addClass('fa-cog fa-spin');
    var $contentWrapper = $('#acf-content-wrapper');
    var postId = $contentWrapper.data('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/field-ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          'post_id': postId
        },
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        $('.fa').removeClass('fa-cog fa-spin');
        $contentWrapper.append(data);
        $('.acf-get-content-button').removeClass().addClass('.acf-get-content-button')
      });
  });
  $('.acf-get-content-button').mouseup(function() {
    if (event.which == 1) {
      $(".acf-get-content-button").hide();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class='fa'></i>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Is it possible to make the cog only shows up after the button is clicked? i mean 1.-the button disappears. 2.-then the cog appears spinning. 3.- the cog disappears when the data appears.

Comment: Did you remove the `fa-spin` that's in the div as per the top of my post instructs? Edited to be more explicit,

Comment: Yes the html is <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> but that displays the static cog at all times. I want the cog to show up when it's loading (after button click). I need to print "<i class="fa fa-spin fa-cog"></i>" after button click not add classes to spin it. I think there's been a misunderstanding.

Comment: Where did you add the other two lines of code? Ok, so you don't want the cog there all the time ok, standby for update....

Comment: I copied your modified snippet. I need to print "<i class="fa fa-spin fa-cog"></i>" after button is clicked not add classes to static cog. The cog should only exist after button is clicked and until data is done loading.
EDIT: Ok sorry! =)

Comment: See update, but it `<i>` won't be visible unless it's in a `<button>` or something that's visible if it's a clickable element.

Comment: Glad I can be of assistance, happy coding. :)